# Invalid RFC 2047 encoding

Tags: java, encoding, jakarta-mail, decoding, rfc

I got some problem in handling the mail subject decoding.

The problem is that I tried decode mail subject and when trying decode one mail I am getting Invalid RFC 2047 encoding exception. But this error appears when trying decode mail subject that mail was sent from smtp office365 server.
My question is: Maybe anybody knows, how fix this exception?